Which Weller adapters fits MLR-21 handle?
I have a Weller MLR-21 handle for fine SMD soldering. But the tip is quite used. I need a new one.
Which tips of MLR-21 handle can have some kind of modern extensions/adapters so it can work with modern Weller tips? Because I assume that tips to Weller MLR-21 are obselete.
The current tip I'm holding in my hand has a diameter of 6.1mm, inner diameter of 4.4mm and length of 25mm.

The question starts with Where to buy is and therefore likely to be closed as off-topic in current form with the reason recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are off-topic

@ChesterGillon changed the question

@jsotola changed the question

You would think that Weller would want to make it easy to figure out which handle is needed for which station and which tips match with which handle, but apparently they don't.
